# Repeat elements in list, but the number of times each element is repeated is provided by a separate list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to repeat each element of a list `x` number of times, where `x` is the corresponding element of the same position in another list.

For example, I have list `A = {1,2,3,4}` and another list `B = {3,1,4,2}` and I'm trying to get `C = {1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4}`.

How do I get `C` from `A` and `B`?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Join @@ MapThread[Table, {A,B}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}

```
Join @@ Table @@@ Transpose @ {A,B}
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}

```
Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {A, B}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}

Also

```
Internal`RepetitionFromMultiplicity @ Transpose[{A, B}]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}

Answer (score 5):

kglr's proposals are nice, and the last (*undocumented*) one is very nice. As a variation, here is a solution using `Inner[]` + `Flatten[]`:

```
Flatten[Inner[ConstantArray, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, List]]
   {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}
```

As kglr notes, a shorter version is

```
Inner[ConstantArray, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, Join]
```

or in version 10 and later,

```
Inner[Table, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, Join]
```

Comment: shorter `Inner[ConstantArray, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, Join]` (+1)

Comment: Indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};

b = {3, 1, 4, 2};
```

Using [`ConstantArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html)

```
c = Flatten[ConstantArray[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@
   Transpose[{a, b}]]

(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4} *)
```

or using [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
c = Flatten[Table[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] & /@
   Transpose[{a, b}]]

(* {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of approaching this is to define a function that carries out the basic task. In this case, to repeat the x element y times.

```
f[x_, y_] := ConstantArray[x, y]; SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

Making this function Listable allows very simple calling method:

```
f[a, b] // Flatten
{1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {3, 1, 4, 2};

Flatten[Table[a[[n]], {n, Length[a]}, {b[[n]]}]]
(* or *)
Flatten[Table[Table[a[[n]], {b[[n]]}], {n, Length[a]}]]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}

```
Flatten[Table[ConstantArray[a[[n]], b[[n]]], {n, Length[a]}]]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4}